# How to get total no of pages in TCPDF?

Tags: cakephp, tcpdf

I used `getNumPages()` function to get the total number of pages in tcpdf, but I didn't get the correct output. What should I do to get the correct number?

Answer (score 14):

Hi I just wanted to add for anyone reading this, that I was using `getNumPages()` like you in the footer and it was giving me trouble because it was showing me the number of pages inserted *up to now*. So I was getting 1/1, 2/2, 3/3, etc.

This is what I tried at first:

```
$this->getPage().'/'.$this->getNumPages()
```

I looked at [example number 3](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_003.phps) and used the following instead to get the correct result.

```
$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages()
```

Comment: This is a good answer - my app using if condition for manual page breaking (better) and "$this->getPage().'/'.$this->getNumPages()" return something like 1/1 2/2 ... n/n for n pages doc

Comment: It returns output as String. when we convert it to integer then output is zero. how to get integer typed current page number and total pages count? Kindly suggest thanks.

Comment: `(int)` and `intval()` both are not working on `getAliasNumPage` and `getAliasNbPages` functions. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->getAliasNumPage()
```

actually returns the string "{:ptp:}", useful for adding the total number of pages after the PDF has been created when you don't know how many pages it will have.

```
$this->PageNo();
```

returns an integer of the current page number which is what I was looking for